# How to avoid DB Concurrency exception when I am updating a table in two different places?

Tags: sql, winforms, exception

I am facing one issue recently.

I have two button which does some update operation in TableA.

Button1 - Will update the TableA using Data table.
Button2 - Will update the TableA using Update statement.

So, when I am finished updating TableA with Button2 click event. The update is succeed. But the problem comes when I try to click Button1 immediately after clicking Button2, I am getting "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

I tried to call the DataTable.AcceptChanges() after updating the table from Button1 click event.

Problem is the data table is loaded when my window is loaded and it has old values, but in mean while I am updating the same table (TableA) with Update statement.

So, my question is how can I resolve this issue? I have googled and at last I am falling here in SOverflow.

Is there any way that I can reload datatable after Button2 click event.

Please look at this code

```
// Add or Update a new Customer
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
            DataTable myTable1 = new DataTable();

            #region Save Button

            if (this.Button2.Text == "Save")
            {
                myTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

                //like this I have many columns to be added

                myTable.Columns.Add("TechReco", typeof(string));
                myTable.Columns.Add("LastUpdatedBy", typeof(string));

                DataRow dr = myTable.NewRow();

                dr["Name"] = txtCustName.Text;
                dr["TDate"] = dateTimePicker2.Value;

                //Like this I have many dataRows to be added

                dr["TaxAmt"] = TextBox13.Text;
                dr["Balance"] = TextBox12.Text;
                if ((ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Select") || (ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Mixed"))
                {
                    dr["PaymentMode"] = ComboBox6.SelectedItem;

                    if (ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Credit Card")
                        dr["card"] = TextBox12.Text;
                    if (ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Cash")
                        dr["cash"] = TextBox12.Text;
                    if (ComboBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Cheque")
                        dr["cheque"] = TextBox12.Text;
                }
                dr["Status"] = ComboBox1.Text;

                //Like this I have many dataRows to be added

                dr["Message"] = TextBox4.Text;

                if (this.TextBox9.Visible == true)
                {
                    dr["PaymentDate"] = TextBox9.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["PaymentDate"] = DBNull.Value;
                }

                if ((this.ComboBox1.Text == "Completed") ||
                (this.ComboBox1.Text == "Sent to Recycle") ||
                (this.ComboBox1.Text == "Cancelled Ticket") ||
                (this.ComboBox1.Text == "Checked Out"))
                {
                    dr["CompletedBy"] = this.CurrentUser;
                }

                dr["SerialNumber"] = textBox14.Text;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text))
                    dr["EstimateCostOfRepair"] = textBox10.Text;

                if (dateTimePicker5.Visible)
                {
                    dr["VisitingDate"] = dateTimePicker5.Value;
                    dr["VisitingTime"] = textBox5.Text;
                }
                dr["TechReco"] = textBox15.Text;

                myTable.TableName = "dbo.WorkOrder";
                TempID = (int)this.util.InsertDataRow(dr, this.DBConnectionString, true);

                this.txtCustName.Items.Add(txtCustName.Text);

                DataTable myTable2 = new DataTable();
                myTable2.TableName = "dbo.Payment_Details";
                myTable2.Columns.Add("WID", typeof(int));
                myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentMode", typeof(string));
                myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentAmount", typeof(decimal));
                myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentDate", typeof(DateTime));

                DataRow dr2 = null;
                if ((this.ComboBox6.Text != "Select") && (this.ComboBox6.Text != "Mixed"))
                {
                    dr2 = myTable2.NewRow();
                    dr2["WID"] = TempID;
                    dr2["PaymentMode"] = this.ComboBox6.Text;
                    // dr2["ApprovalBox"] = this.ApproveBox1.Text; // not needed
                    // dr2["AVBox"] = this.comboBox2.Text;  // not neede
                    dr2["PaymentAmount"] = this.TextBox12.Text;
                    dr2["PaymentDate"] = this.TextBox9.Value;
                    this.util.InsertDataRow(dr2, this.DBConnectionString, false);
                }

                myTable1.TableName = "dbo.WorkOrder_Details";
                myTable1.Columns.Add("WID", typeof(int));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(decimal));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
                // myTable1.Columns.Add("Tax", typeof(short));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Tax", typeof(int));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("TDate", typeof(DateTime));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("PaymentDate", typeof(DateTime));
                // int LCDServiceCount = 0;
                // int EnvFeeCount = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < this.WGrid.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                    // this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                    {
                        //LCDServiceCount = (CountLCDServices(this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())) ? LCDServiceCount+ 1 : LCDServiceCount;
                        //EnvFeeCount = (CountEnvironmentalFees(this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())) ? EnvFeeCount+ 1 : EnvFeeCount;

                        DataRow dr1 = myTable1.NewRow();
                        dr1["WID"] = TempID;
                        dr1["Name"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value;
                        dr1["Qty"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value;
                        dr1["Price"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value;
                        dr1["Amount"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value;
                        dr1["Tax"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value;
                        dr1["TDate"] = this.dateTimePicker2.Value;
                        dr1["Status"] = this.ComboBox1.Text.ToString();

                        if (this.TextBox9.Visible == true)
                            dr1["PaymentDate"] = this.TextBox9.Value;
                        else
                            dr1["PaymentDate"] = DBNull.Value;

                        this.util.InsertDataRow(dr1, this.DBConnectionString, false);
                    }
                }

                this.util.ExecuteSQLQuery("delete from WorkOrder_Details where Qty is NULL");
                this.Label5.Text = TempID.ToString();
                FillData("dbo.WorkOrder");

                MessageBox.Show("Workorder Created", "ABCD", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Update Button
            else
            {
                string id = Label5.Text;

                //this.dataTbl.Clear();

                DataRow[] row = this.dataTbl.Select(string.Format("ID = {0}", id));

                if (row.Count() == 1)
                {
                    row[0]["Name"] = txtCustName.Text.ToString();
                    //Like this I have many dataRows to be added
                    row[0]["LastUpdatedBy"] = this.CurrentUser;

                    if (this.TextBox9.Visible == true)
                        row[0]["PaymentDate"] = this.TextBox9.Value;
                    else
                        row[0]["PaymentDate"] = DBNull.Value;
                }

                this.util.UpdateDB("dbo.WorkOrder", this.dataTbl);   //I am getting exception at this place 
                this.dataTbl.AcceptChanges();                        // DB Concurrency exception updated effected 0 records of 1 record found

                string qry = string.Format("Delete from WorkOrder_Details where WID= {0}", id);
                this.util.ExecuteSQLQuery(qry);

                DataTable myTable2 = util.FillData("Select * from Payment_Details");
                DataRow[] row2 = myTable2.Select(string.Format("WID = {0}", id));

                if (row2.Count() == 0)
                {
                    myTable2 = new DataTable();
                    myTable2.TableName = "dbo.Payment_Details";
                    myTable2.Columns.Add("WID", typeof(int));
                    myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentMode", typeof(string));
                    // myTable2.Columns.Add("ApprovalBox", typeof(string)); //
                    // myTable2.Columns.Add("AVBox", typeof(string));
                    myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentAmount", typeof(decimal));
                    myTable2.Columns.Add("PaymentDate", typeof(DateTime));

                    DataRow dr2 = null;
                    if ((this.ComboBox6.Text != "Select") && (this.ComboBox6.Text != "Mixed"))
                    {
                        dr2 = myTable2.NewRow();
                        dr2["WID"] = id;
                        dr2["PaymentMode"] = this.ComboBox6.Text;
                        // dr2["ApprovalBox"] = this.ApproveBox1.Text; //
                        // dr2["AVBox"] = this.comboBox2.Text;
                        dr2["PaymentAmount"] = this.TextBox12.Text;
                        dr2["PaymentDate"] = this.TextBox9.Value;
                        this.util.InsertDataRow(dr2, this.DBConnectionString, false);
                    }
                }


                myTable1 = new DataTable();
                myTable1.TableName = "dbo.WorkOrder_Details";
                myTable1.Columns.Add("WID", typeof(int));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(decimal));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
                // myTable1.Columns.Add("Tax", typeof(short));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Tax", typeof(int));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("TDate", typeof(DateTime));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("StatusChanged", typeof(DateTime));
                myTable1.Columns.Add("PaymentDate", typeof(DateTime));

                // int LCDServiceCount = 0;
                // int EnvFeeCount = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < this.WGrid.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Length != 0 &&
                        this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                    //this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                    {
                        //LCDServiceCount = (CountLCDServices(this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())) ? LCDServiceCount + 1 : LCDServiceCount;
                        //EnvFeeCount = (CountEnvironmentalFees(this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())) ? EnvFeeCount + 1 : EnvFeeCount;

                        DataRow dr1 = myTable1.NewRow();
                        dr1["WID"] = id;
                        dr1["Name"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value;
                        dr1["Qty"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value;
                        dr1["Price"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value;
                        dr1["Amount"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value;
                        dr1["Tax"] = this.WGrid.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value;
                        dr1["TDate"] = this.dateTimePicker2.Value;
                        dr1["Status"] = this.ComboBox1.Text.ToString();
                        dr1["StatusChanged"] = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }

                this.util.ExecuteSQLQuery("delete from WorkOrder_Details where Qty is NULL");
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated", "ABCD", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            #endregion

            string SearchSQL = "Select TDate Date,ID Ticket_No,Status,Name,Phone,Model,Balance,ISNULL(NULLIF(PaymentMode, 'Select'), '') as PaymentMode, PaymentDate, CreatedBy, CompletedBy from WorkOrder Order by ID DESC";
            this.WrdGrid.DataSource = util.FillData(SearchSQL);

            FillDataWorder_Detail(this.Label5.Text);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Another technician already updated this ticket, close the ticket and re-open it again");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

and this is the normal update statement I have used in another button click event.

```
Update Table1 SET PromoisedDays =="+newPromisedDays+" SET WHERE <Condition>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: This is the code where using Data Table and other piece of code is normal update statement. I am not pasting the code using Update statement (cause the code is not with me now). Here is the link http://pastie.org/9504677